# REGEX: replacing everything between two strings, but not the start/end strings

Tags: php, regex

I am not the best with RegEx... I have some PHP code:

```
$pattern = '/activeAds = \[(.*?)\]/si';
$modData = preg_replace($pattern,'TEST',$data);
```

So I have a JavaScript file, and it declares and array:

```
var activeAds = [];
```

I need this to populate the array with my string, or if the array already has a string inside it, i want to replace it with my string (in this case "TEST").

Right now, my REGEX is replacing everything, including my start and end, i need to only replace whats between.

I'm left with:

```
var TEST;
```

TIA

Comment: Doesn't that mean that you just want to replace the contents of the array with your string, regardless of what is or isn't there?

Comment: I'd like to warn you that JS is too complex to be parsed with regex. You could very easily run into trouble (for example, if there's any nesting `activeAds = [1, [1,2]]`, or if there're different variables like `my_activeAds = ...; other_activeAds = ...` it will screw over everything). There are **many** things that could break down.

Comment: ... and even simple things like having more than one space when you expected a single space could break things ... Only do this if you know exactly what the code looks like, and even then, consider using `\b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture what's before and what's after the part you want replacing:

```
$pattern = '/(activeAds = \[).*?(\])/si';
```

After capturing these parts, you can keep them and replace the part in the middle:

```
$modData = preg_replace($pattern, '\1TEST\2', $data);
```

Comment: This works. thank you, do you think this is the best method? I was thinking i should be using something more simple, or a lookahead/lookbehind

Comment: This isn't really necessary since your capture groups match constant strings. You could easily do: `$modData = preg_replace($pattern, 'activeAds = [TEST]', $data)` while using the OP's `$pattern`. Much cleaner IMO.

Comment: @JoelGrannas, I think lookaround is more complicated than something like this (and it's often slower, too). Do however take note of the comments to the question - this is very unsafe, unless you know for sure that this is the exact string you will always need to parse.

Comment: @NullUserException, I thought of doing that at first, but I think this is easier to type if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this, mine is below:

```
$data    = array("activeAds = testing123");
$pattern = "/activeAds\s?=\s?(.*)/";
$result  = preg_replace($pattern,"activeAds = TEST", $data);
var_dump($result);
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that the `\s?` here allow for an optional space.